# Can not find the motor commands

Tags: vbscript

I have a spanish lanugue XPSP2 machine runnning a .vbs logon script that is recieving the following error

"No se encuentra el motor de secuencias ds commandos "VBscript" para la secuncia"

rough translation is

"Can not find the sequence of motor commands ds "VBscript" for secuncia"

Does any one have any insight as to what this error might be referring?

Answer (score 2):

It's no 'motor' it's the scripting 'engine':
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/222837/es
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/222837/en

(The links show the translation. I'm not sure if they have something to do with your problem.)

Comment: I don't think you've linked to the correct error, but +1 for showing how to do direct translation between KB articles

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the script you could add msgbox() at various parts in the script to try to see what specific line is failing.  That is the way I trouble shoot vbscripts.  There are more elegant ways to do the debugging but it is quick and dirty.  Just remember to remove them afterward.  =)

So...

Msgbox("Phase1")
Msgbox("Phase2")
Msgbox("Phase3")
Msgbox("Phase4")

so if Phase 2 shows up before the error message that means the problem is after Phase 2 but before Phase 3.  Space out the msgboxes between your code.  Once you isolate the area you can then be very specific about the location of the msgboxes and find the exact line that is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You may be running into the problem discussed on [this thread](http://www.baluart.net/articulo/como-actualizar-el-windows-pirata).  In case your Spanish is weak, pirata is "pirated."